# Find area of the surface $z=b-ax^2$ where 0≤ x ≤ $\sqrt(b/a)$ , -c ≤y ≤ c

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I want to find the area of the surface $z=b-ax^2$ where 0≤ x ≤ $\sqrt(b/a)$  , -c ≤y ≤ c.

I have parametrized the surface as $\textbf{r}(x,y)=(x, y, b-ax^2)$. I then use the formula
\begin{gather*}
    \iint |r'_{x}   \times r'_{y}| dxdy 
\end{gather*}
to calculate the area of the surface which gives me

\begin{gather*}
    \iint \sqrt(4a^2x^2+1) dxdy \end{gather*}

I set the limits to be 0≤ x ≤ $\sqrt(b/a)$  , -c ≤y ≤ c and end up with the wrong answer. The answer is supposed to be (c$\sqrt2(b+\sqrt(b/a))$. I think I do something wrong when I set my limits, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: plot and visualize the function

Comment: the book answer seems wrong to me. your integral is set up correctly.